# Referencing image in assets folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have sampleposition.png in my assets folder, and a page called myPage.js in my components folder. How do I reference the sampleposition.png in my assets folder from myPage.js. I've tried `src="../assets/sampleposition.png" /` but that doesn't seem to be working.

[image]

Comment: The idiomatic way to achieve what you want is to use a bundler (such as webpack) and a "compiler" (such as babeljs), and instead use an `import` statement so you can use the image as a component. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66410782/how-to-load-image-react-babel

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644265/correct-path-for-img-on-react-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/), the process is fairly easy and straight-forward.

Are you `import`ing it or doing something like `<img src="../whatever/>`?  You need to be `import`ing so that the build will know how to access it at runtime.  See [Adding Images, Fonts, and Files](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/)

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.png'; // Tell webpack this JS file uses this image

console.log(logo); // /logo.84287d09.png

function Header() {
  // Import result is the URL of your image
  return <img src={logo} alt="Logo" />;
}

export default Header;
```

If you aren't, you need to be serving the content statically and referencing the static content address or use a build/bundle tool to put the content into a place that is known ahead of time which is what the create-react-app tool sets up for you.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you! I never knew I needed to import it.

Answer (score 0):

Import your image and use it in the code. This should do it according to your requirement.

```
import React from 'react';
import myImage from '../assets/sampleposition.png'; 



function YourFunction() {
  
  return 
        <img src={myImage} alt="myImage" />;
}

export default YourFunction;
```